# Directus 7 in docker add user

Tags: directus

I have installed Directus 7 in docker-compose as stated here [Directus 7 in docker](https://github.com/directus/docker/tree/master/examples/simple)

but the command

```
docker-compose run installer install --email your@email.com --password somepass
```

just hangs until I press CTRL+C.

Who could help how to add a user?

Comment: We merged a PR fixing this, but there was no release yet. https://github.com/directus/docker/pull/65

Comment: Thank you! Meanwhile here the overcome of the problem is: after the above docker-compose run, one needs to execute:
docker exec -it <your-api-container-name> php ../bin/directus user:password -e your@email.com -p somepass

Comment: awesome! :) glad it worked out